# can't write to database psql - INSERT INTO syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

still new to this but i have a PSQL table that's connected to my python(flask) app
with this columns description

> id    integer Auto Increment [nextval('users_id_seq')]
>
> name  character varying
>
> pw    character varying
>
> email character varying

and this function that excute after the user visits `@app.route("/registed" ,methods=["POST"])`

```
def registed():
Name1 = "test"
Email1 = "test1"
pw1 = "test2"
pwh = "test3"


db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,pw,email) VALUES (Name1,pw1,Email1)")
db.commit()

return render_template("registed.html",name=Name1,email=Email1,pw=pw1,pwh=pwh)
```

it keep coming bk with this error

> LINE 1: INSERT INTO users (name,pw,email) VALUES (Name1,pw1,Email1)
>                                                     ^
>   HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "users.name".
>    [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (name,pw,email) VALUES (Name1,pw1,Email1)'] (Background on this error at: http://*****/*/***)

i used heroku for this test project

Comment: db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,pw,email) VALUES ('+Name1+','+pw1+','+Email1+')"), shouldn't it be concanated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly pass variables into SQL query like this.
It can only be done if the values you're passing in are literals. 
To pass in variables **placeholders** need to be used. 
So, the `db.execute` line should be changed to -->

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,pw,email) VALUES (:name,:pw,:email)", {"name":Name1, "pw":pw1, "email":Email1})
```

What we're doing here is, we replace the variables by placeholders in the query by using a colon( : ) in front of them and then passing in their values as python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.execute("insert into users (name,pw,email) values (?, ?, ?)", (Name1,
pw1, Email1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the values as :

query = "INSERT INTO users (name,pw,email) VALUES ('%s','%s', '%s')"%(Name1, pw1, Email1)
db.execute(query)
db.commit()

Answer (score -1):

Try this as Name1 pw1 and Email1 are variables.

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,pw,email) VALUES ("+Name1+","+pw1+","+Email1+")")
```

Comment: [Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)

Comment: Of course the author of the documentation is too expressive ;) However, the rule can prevent from an sql injection.

Comment: didnt work either -----

 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (name,pw,email) VALUES (cxx,dasdasdasdasdas,xxxx@aaasda.aa)'] (Background on this error at: http://****/***/**/

Comment: db.execute("INSERT INTO players(player_name) VALUES(%(name)s)", {"name":name}) . Once try this,